Number string does not get quotes with yaml-cpp
This code:
...
YAML::Node myNode;
myNode["some-value"] = "3";
...
YAML::Emitter emitter;
emitter << myNode;
...

Produces the following output:
some-value: 3

This leads to problems when validating the result with a JSON schema, since 3 is not recognized as a string.
How can I add (double) quotes to this value?
PS: emitter << YAML::DoubleQuoted << myNode; is not really an option, since this is called only on the root node of my node-tree. But the node I want to wrap in qutotes is somewhere deep down in that tree.

But ofcourse you get JSON issues, you are writing YAML. For json use the excellent nlohman/json library

Your example code should really show that you are setting one child node but calling emitter for a root node. That way the question may be considered for reopening or a better dupe can be found.

If "some-value": "3" is a satisfiable solution for you, this can be done
YAML::Emitter emitter;
emitter.SetStringFormat(YAML::DoubleQuoted);
emitter << myNode;


I tried that, but it puts pretty much everything in quotes. This is not neccessary and makes the resulting file a lot harder to read.

Then, the JSON schema should be modified. Anyway YAML is not JSON and you likely will get other issues now or later.

Use YAML::DoubleQuoted as a stream manipulator for the single value being emitted, instead of as a setting that affects the whole stream, eg: emitter << YAML::DoubleQuoted << myNode;

But how can you do that for only a single node? In my code, I create a huge tree of nodes, and in the end pass only the root node to the emitter for serialization. The problematic node is only a single one in that tree.
